# Android studio Gradle is not building?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have upgraded my android studio to 3.2 whenever i try to compile my projects i got an error

> Connection timed out: connect

I have been reading so many articles in stackoverflow and i got about setting proxy in gradle my computer is not using any proxy.My question how to set proxy for gradle and what are

> systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com

should i have to put proxy.company.com gradle link?

> systemProp.http.proxyPort

thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to set a proxy if you don't need one?

Comment: @Henry the solution given for Connection timed out: connect

 is setting proxy.

Comment: Several reasons can cause a "connection timed out". You must find out what it is in your case and then take appropriate action. You said you are not using a proxy so this possible reason is ruled out.